# Accessing Parametric object from category

Tags: prolog, categories, logtalk

how to Access Parametric object from a ategory

```
:- category(attributes).

    :- public(info/1).
    info(Value) :- arg(1,_Array_,Value).

:- end_category.

:- object(array(_Array_),imports([attributes])).
```

this does not work ...

```
 *     Singleton variable: _Array_
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As entity parameters are logical variables, simply share them between the object and the category:

```
:- category(attributes(_Array_)).

    :- public(info/1).
    info(Value) :-
        arg(1, _Array_, Value).

:- end_category.


:- object(array(_Array_),
    imports(attributes(_Array_))).

:- end_object.
```